# data manipulation in R

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I have a number of couples `(x, y)`, with `x` a number and `y` a binary indicator.

I would like to add 0.1 to the x component for each couple `(x, 0)` such that there exists a couple `(x, 1)`.

For example

```
x y 
1 0 
2 0 
2 0 
3 0 
3 1 
4 1
```

would become

```
x   y 
1   0 
2   0 
2   0 
3.1 0 
3   1 
4   1
```

Can you help me to do this in `R`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(1,2,2,3,3,4), y = c(0,0,0,0,1,1))
 within(df, x[y==0][x[y==0] %in% x[y==1]] <- x[y==0][x[y==0] %in% x[y==1]]+.1)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(data.table)
# Create your sample data:
df<-data.frame(x=c(1,2,2,3,3,4), y=c(0,0,0,0,1,1))

# Convert data.frame to data.table:
dt<-data.table(df,key="x,y")

# Get x values where y==1, create a secondary table of (x, 0),
# join it to the original table and then update x
dt[dt[y==1,list(x,y=0)],x:=x+0.1]

dt
#      x y
# 1: 1.0 0
# 2: 2.0 0
# 3: 2.0 0
# 4: 3.1 0
# 5: 3.0 1
# 6: 4.0 1
```